# R - Subseting data by searching a list with wildcards across multiple columns

Tags: r

I am a relatively new R user who is doing analysis of administrative health data.

This community has been a great help at advancing my own understanding of R and its' functions - however after spending an entire day stuck with this issue, and without being able to find a solution (thus far), I have decided to post for the first time.

Briefly,

My data set contains multiple diagnostic vectors (25 columns in total) can include a variety of 'diagnostic codes' or be NA.

Each row corresponds to one encounter with the health system (which may include multiple diagnostic codes - up to the 25), however I am only interested in the encounters that have a diagnostic code (in one of the 25 fields) for a particular condition of interest.

The challenge I am having is that the disease diagnostic codes I want to search for correspond to the beginning of the specific diagnostic codes that are in the actual data. (e.g. I want to find all codes that start with M16 and M17 - and these in the data will appear as M161 or M1611, etc.)

I have found some code through this site which has allowed me to search the 25 diagnostic code fields in the data, looking for a specified list of diagnostic codes of interest, and subset the data to only those encounters where the codes of interest occur.

The issue I am having is that I have to specify the codes exactly, as I have not been able to work a wildcard into the function to search for any diagnostic code (eg. M1611, M1622) using just the first few characters (e.g. M16).

I have created some simple data to replicate what I CAN do right now. What I would like to be able to do is to use a list codes that I specify (e.g. M16, M17 with a wildcard operator to come up with the same outcome ('data-subset').

I suspect this will involve grep, but for the life of me I have not been able to come up with a way of doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I hope that I have provided a clear enough question and code.

```
#make a simple data set
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
pr1 = c("M151", "M141", "M161", "M177", "M197", "M200")
pr2 = c("M100", "M101", "M120", "M135", "M144", "M190")
pr3 = c("M210", "M205", "M167", "M121", "M166", "M174")
data <-  data.frame(id,pr1,pr2,pr3)

#list of columns to search
list <- names(data)[2:4]

#codes of interest
codes <- c("M161","M174","M177","M167","M166")

# subset the data to include only those that have a code of interest
data_subset <- data[apply(apply(as.matrix(data[list]), c(1,2), `%in%`, codes), 1, any),]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Edit 1 for clarity - my ultimate goal would be to produce an output as follows:

```
row.names   id  pr1     pr2     pr3
3            3  M161    M120    M167
4            4  M177    M135    M121
5            5  M197    M144    M166
6            6  M200    M190    M174
```

It retains only the rows from the original set that had a value of interest, but otherwise maintains the structure of the data.frame. As mentioned below - an added challenge is I am working in a secure research environment where I have no internet access, and thus can not install packages at will...

Edit 2: Another solution (via a brilliant friend) in addition to that one posted below:

```
# regexes that we want to match
regexcodes <- c("^M16", "^M17")

# subset the data to include only those that have a code of interest
data_subset <- data[apply(apply(as.matrix(data[list]), c(1,2), function(u){
  # u corresponds to the actual string

  # this combines your regex into the following: "^M16|^M17" - it is basically
  # just an OR operator in a regex
  combined_regex <- paste(regexcodes,collapse="|")

  # grepl returns true if u matches the regex
  grepl(combined_regex, u, perl=TRUE)
}), 1, any),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick way to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringi)

long_form = 
  data %>%
  gather(diagnostic, code, -id) %>%
  merge(data_frame(partial_code = codes)) %>%
  filter(code %>% stri_detect_fixed(partial_code))
```

Edit: Here is how to recover matching rows from the original data:

```
data %>%
  semi_join(long_form)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! I have edited the above question to try and be more explicit about the output that I am looking for. Basically I am just looking to retain the rows that have a code of interest, but want to make sure that all the other columns are retained. Any additional comments are welcomed, an added challenge is that I am working in an environment without internet access (secured) thus I am unable to install packages at will...

Comment: I've added an edit that I think does what you are looking for. If I had to work using R but I wasn't able to install packages I'd probably quit.