# Adding indicator variable to dataframe after searching from list (with wildcard) across multiple columns

Tags: r

I posted yesterday with a related question that has since been resolved: see [R - Subseting data by searching a list with wildcards across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055742/r-subseting-data-by-searching-a-list-with-wildcards-across-multiple-columns)

This previous question related to subsetting based on a list of codes with an added 'wildcard' across a number of columns.

My question today is similar in that I would like to create an indicator variable in the dataframe that indicates whether or not one of those predefined codes from a list (M16, M17) with a wildcard (^M16, ^M17) appears anywhere across a number of specified columns (pr1, pr2, pr3)

Beginning dataset

```
#make a simple data set
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
pr1 = c("M151", "M141", "M161", "M177", "M197", "M200")
pr2 = c("M100", "M101", "M120", "M135", "M144", "M190")
pr3 = c("M210", "M205", "M167", "M121", "M166", "M174")
data <-  data.frame(id,pr1,pr2,pr3)
```

Desired data set having searched through a list of M16 and M17 with wildcards

```
#desired output
id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
pr1 = c("M151", "M141", "M161", "M177", "M197", "M200")
pr2 = c("M100", "M101", "M120", "M135", "M144", "M190")
pr3 = c("M210", "M205", "M167", "M121", "M166", "M174")
indicator = c("0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1")

data <-  data.frame(id,pr1,pr2,pr3,indicator)
```

I am really struggling to incorporate wildcards into my coding - an unfortunately with a limited time frame to work I do not have days to work it out.

Edit 1: clarifying my question with greater detail

I would like if I could feed a list of a) columns to search, and b) codes to search for the function. I have tried to modify the answer given below but it is telling me that 'there is an error in row sums as x is not numeric'.

```
columns <- c("pr1","pr2","pr3")
code <- c("M16", "M17")
code <- paste("^",code,sep="")
combined_code = paste(code, sep="")
for (n in names(data)){x <- cbind(x, grepl(combined_code, data[columns]))}
data$indicator <- rowSums(x)>1
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `paste` the 'pr' columns together and then use `grep` to create the 'indicator' column

```
data$indicator <- +(grepl('\\b(M16|M17)', 
               do.call(paste, data[grep('^pr', names(data))])))
data$indicator
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: this is a nice solution!

Comment: I agree - thank you both for your help! For the record, is it possible to specify the M16|M17 etc. as an object if it were a longer list (say 20 or 30 codes)?

Comment: @health_code If you have a vector of 20 or 30 codes ie. `v1 <- c('M16', 'M17', 'M18'); pat <- paste0('\\b(', paste(v1, collapse="|"), ')')` then you can use the `pat` inside `grepl` i.e. `grepl(pat, do.call(paste, ...`

Comment: @akrun Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty quick and dirty clumsy but functional solution.

```
for (n in names(data)){x<- cbind(x,grepl("^M16|^M17", data[,n]))}
data$indicator <- apply(x,1, any)
```

Good luck on the Hw.